# How should i implement different pages for different content

Tags: wordpress

I am making my first custom WordPress theme and i ran into my first big wall.

I have different content. I have videos and articles and photos. I need to display these pages differently.

Should i just add a category and display them differently that way? i think this is easy but i am having trouble Googling this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create custom template for each page and then set them according to your requirement.

- [Reference Link](http://codex.wordpress.org/Pages)
- [Example Link](http://www.expand2web.com/blog/custom-page-template-wordpress/)

Answer (score 1):

this may help :

[Creating_Your_Own_Page_Templates](http://codex.wordpress.org/Pages#Creating_Your_Own_Page_Templates)

[wordpress custome Pages](http://codex.wordpress.org/Pages)